# Spring Boot - Download a file from GCP Bucket

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I've a Spring Boot Application and I have to develop an API to download a file from GCP bucket.
So I have the download path and the name of the bucket, e.g.

```
my_bucket = "bucketTest"
download_path = bucketTest + "/file.txt"
```

Before I start writing the code for download, what are the preliminary steps? I read that I need a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable, where can I find it?
Once I set this environment variable, do I just need to write the download code or are there some setup inside the controller function?

Comment: What's your code? Where are you stuck? Meanwhile you can have a look to ADC on Google Cloud and how the gcp libraries work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this topic can help : [spring controller download file GCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920135/how-to-download-a-file-from-google-cloud-storage-and-return-it-in-spring-control)

For `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` it allows an application to be authenticated on `GCP`.

- Firstly you have to create a service account on `IAM GCP page` with the needed privileges.
- Download a json key for this service account.
- Set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var that targets on the path of the Service Account json key, before to start `main` and entrypoint of your `Spring Boot` application.